# Pycharm: testing from anther computer in local network

Tags: django, pycharm

I am using Pycharm and testing on local dev server. All goes well until I try to connect to the local dev server from another laptop (windows).

My dev server is `127.0.0.1:8000` on a mac. On the second computer, I am able to ping the server's LAN ip `10.0.2.2` successfully. But enter `10.0.2.2:8000` in browser address bar doesn't connect to anything.

`telnet 10.0.2.2 8000` in command line also fails.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For beginner like me, screenshot can help.

If leaving Host field to be empty, it will default to 127.0.0.1, which is not we want in such situation.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Listen to address 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1
This means it will listen to all, you can listen to specific IP but this would work on both local and network.

Comment: How to set this `listen` for pycharm dev server?

Comment: usually it's --address=0.0.0.0 in your run config in parameters