# Pycharm 404 error when accessing on another computer via ip

Tags: localhost, pycharm

I'm trying to access my work on another computer on my network. I'm able to access the file through localhost:8000/ on my local machine, but not through ip on my local machine or on another computer. Confirmed there is no firewall blocking (I am able to access my Webstorm files via ip on both local and external computers). I have tried changing my port to something other than 8000 :

My Debugger settings are: Built-in server: can accept external connections (checked) and Port: 65322.

Sometimes when I try to connect, I get err_connection_refused, but most recently it's a Pycharm page saying 404 Not Found.

Answer (score 0):

This post answered my question:

[Pycharm: testing from anther computer in local network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17257110/pycharm-testing-from-anther-computer-in-local-network)

I had to change my host from 127.0.0.0 to 0.0.0.0 to allow access from all.